# How to implement NetBeans Installer(NBI) for our own NetBeans Java application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I wanna make executable installer for my Java application developed using NetBeans IDE v8. My Question was, How to implement NBI(NetBeans Installler) for my Java application. In their weblink https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-nbi.html they demonstrated using sample application.. But I couldn't get option(like they have specified for sample application in tutorial) for my Java application.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is built right into NetBeans.

1. Right click on the project name.
2. Choose "Properties"
3. In the "Deployment" section, check the "Enable Native Packaging" option
   [image]
4. Close the dialog
5. Right click on the project name
6. Choose "Package As -> EXE Installer"

   [image]

This assumes a standard (Ant based) Java project. I don't know if this is available when using Maven.

Comment: OK. Thank you ..But I am getting an error i.e exception like java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "iscc"... and also "Error: JavaFX native packager requires external Inno Setup 5+ tools installed and included on PATH  to create EXE installer. See www.jrsoftware.org/"

Comment: Sorry, no idea I have never used JavaFX.

Comment: Ok.. Do you know about Exception like IOException: Cannot run program "iscc"..Do you you have any answer for this?

Comment: See the NetBeans manual for a list of requirements for each installer type: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40938_01/doc.74/e40142/build_japps.htm#BABDGHDF

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. I installed Inno setup software and tried.. But there is an problem with sqlite db.. It is not migrating with exe file..

Comment: The answer provided is for Java Packaging and not for NBI!

Comment: @adamretter: that option **is** available for NetBeans Platform projects (and the question never talked about a NetBeans _platform_ project - only about a "Java Project")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the question asks "How to implement NBI(NetBeans Installler) for my Java application", however the accepted response does not use NBI.